# doxygen reporting an enddot error in 1.8.2.1

Tags: doxygen, graphviz, dot

I have a very odd error. I'm running squeeze that has a default version of doxygen of 1.7.1. The following dot code works fine

```
@dot
        digraph mpeg {
            init [shape=box, label="video_init"];
            loop [shape=box, label="Loop"];
            setfds [shape=box, label="video_set_fds"];
            select [shape=diamond, label="Select"];
            endloop [shape=box, label="Loop end"];
            term [shape=box, label="video_term"];
            process [shape=box, label="video_process"];
            handler [shape=box, label="Video callback handler"];

            init->loop;
            loop->setfds;
            setfds->select;
            select->process [label="Action needed"];
            process->select [label="Return control"];
            select->endloop;
            endloop->loop;
            endloop->term;
            process->handler [label="Report video event"];
        }
    @enddot
```

As I wanted to use the @snippet call, which was added in 1.7.5, I have installed the Wheezy version of the package which seems to work fine apart from the above generates the following error

> warning: unexpected command enddot

I cannot see anything wrong with the code, and 1.7.1 didn't have an issue. Removing the above section creates the correct documentation, so why is an error being flagged when there doesn't appear to be one? This code is inside a .dox file instead of a header file as I'm trying to keep overview information out of header files to keep them less cluttered.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you see the same problem with the curent version of doxygen (1.8.5) ?

Comment: @Ian: Tip for a newcomer - it's appropriate and courteous to respond when respondents ask for more information (even if the answer is 'I don't know').  I myself am waiting for an answer to albert's question before suggesting any potential fixes for your problem.  If you've solved the problem then please "answer" it yourself so it's not left as an unanswered question that some of us are putting thought to occasionally.